# How I can call a post function with a link

Tags: javascript, html, express

I have a navbar, and I want to have also a tag where I can call my post function. The problem is that I don't know how to call it with a link. If you see to my navbar code, you see that I am working with links.

Here is my post function

```
app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session) {
        try{
            console.log(`${req.session.userdata.name} logged out at ${getTime()} at the devide ${req.ip.slice(7)} ${req.ips}`)
        } catch(error){
            console.log(`"Err" logged out at ${getTime()} at the devide ${req.ip.slice(7)} ${req.ips}`);
        }
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res.redirect('/');
            };
        });
    };
});
```

And here is my navbar code

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="/user/:id/home">Home</a>
    <a href="/">Login</a>
    <a href="/info">Info</a>
</div>
```

I also tried this

```
<form action="/logout" method="post">
  <a href="#" id = "logout" title="save logout"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"> </i>Logout</a>
</form>
```

Comment: You can not make a POST request with just a link in HTML alone. Your two basic options are either AJAX/fetch (for a background request), or to submit a form.

Comment: (Btw., I am pretty sure I responded to pretty much the exact same question yesterday already?)

Comment: Yes but since it hasn't got any comment more I reupload it. Also i tried the form submit as you can see it on the last code

Comment: Please don’t do that - this site would be chaos in no time, if everybody deleted and re-created their questions, just because they got a bit _impatient_ while waiting for an response.

Comment: That is not how forms work, they are not submitted by clicking a link, you need a submit _button_ for that. If you want to use a link, then you need to add a click handler, that then calls the form’s `submit` method.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. As far as i understand you mean that what the other guy posted. Well that for some reason didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the `click` event of the link, And `submit` the form using javascript.

> Here I am using JQuery,

```js
$('#logout').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  $('#logout_form').submit();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/logout" method="post" id='logout_form'>
  <a href="#" id="logout" title="save logout">
     <i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"> </i>Logout
  </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. When i try t run this and try to click it the only thing that happens is that at the end of the url only a # applies.

Comment: @Taris then the event handler was not bound correctly, so that the _normal_ link action was performed. (Are you even using jQuery in your project? If not, you need to rewrite this to however your client-side JS library does event handling, or rewrite it to vanilla JS, if you are not using any.)